# Sitecore 8.0 crashing w3wp.exe when choosing if a version is unpublished or published

Tags: iis, versions

I have an instance of sitecore 8.0 setup (CD and CM separate servers).

On the CM server we've noticed that if a page has multiple versions, and a user then tried to mark one of the versions as unpublished we get an error on the server itself:
An unhandled Microsoft .Net Framework exception occurred in w3wp.exe and iis will restart. The change does actually go through but with the app pool refreshing whenever this happens its making publishing and unpublishing and extremely long process.

Is this something anyone else has faced before, any suggestions on where to look further?

I've exported the process as it crashed and ran in through debugdiag to get the following:

```
[[GCFrame]] 
[[GCFrame]] 
[[HelperMethodFrame_1OBJ] (System.Threading.Monitor.Enter)] System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(System.Object) 
System_ni!System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo)+190 
Sitecore.ContentTesting.Pipelines.GetScreenShotForURL.GenerateScreenShot.GenerateScreenshot(Sitecore.ContentTesting.Pipelines.GetScreenShotForURL.GetScreenShotForURLArgs)+123 
DynamicClass.(System.Object, System.Object[])+4a 
Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(Sitecore.Pipelines.PipelineArgs)+148 
Sitecore.ContentTesting.Pipelines.GetScreenShotForURL.GetScreenShotForURLPipeline.Run(Sitecore.ContentTesting.Pipelines.GetScreenShotForURL.GetScreenShotForURLArgs)+f7 
Sitecore.ContentTesting.Events.GenerateScreenshot.ScreenshotWorker(System.Object)+217 
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)+162 
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)+14 
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()+70 
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()+152 
[[DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame]] 
[[ContextTransitionFrame]] 
[[DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame]]
```

inside the log files we see:

```
8144 12:24:57 ERROR Unhandled exception detected. The ASP.NET worker process will be terminated. 
Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
Message: The system cannot find the file specified
Source: System
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Sitecore.ContentTesting.Pipelines.GetScreenShotForURL.GenerateScreenShot.GenerateScreenshot(GetScreenShotForURLArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.ContentTesting.Pipelines.GetScreenShotForURL.GetScreenShotForURLPipeline.Run(GetScreenShotForURLArgs args)
   at Sitecore.ContentTesting.Events.GenerateScreenshot.ScreenshotWorker(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks like an issue for Sitecore Support. The ContentTesting mechanics are getting in a twist, trying to generate a valid screenshot.

Comment: Might not hurt to check that your `<DataFolder>\tools\phantomjs\phantomjs.exe` file exists. There is also a `sc-ee.js` file in that directory next to phantomjs.exe.

Comment: Also, screenshots are trying to be written to `<web root>\temp\screenshots`. I would double check those three things prior to going to support. If it solves your problem, I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: nailed it on the head. for some reason the entire tools folder was missing, (along with submit queue and serialization). cheers :-)